# Writing horribly slow on drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Half a year ago I installed a hybrid SSHD drive in my father's laptop. Initially it performed really well, but lately his CAD program takes 5-10 minutes to save a file. I eliminated the anti-virus program as the root cause, and now I think it is a HDD issue. Checkdisk did not find any errors.

How do I test my theory about the HDD failure?
What can cause this?

Comment: The best way to test the HDD health is to use the HDD manufacturer diagnostics tool. Look at the manufacturer web site and run the tests it offers.

Comment: True. Manufacturers tools, or barring that any S.M.A.R.T. reading capable tool.